# SQL stored procedure call from UI

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a MVC UI-> WCF Service-> SQL Backend.

On the UI, I have 2 drop-downs...On Page load, drop-down1 needs to be populated; based on the value of drop-down1, we populate drop-down2 and based on the two selections, a message (varchar(650)) is displayed. Both the drop-downs contain questions/ sentences.

These combinations are stored in a matrix table in SQL.

Is it better to have three back-end calls (populate ddl1, populate ddl2, show msg) or bring in the entire matrix in one call to the front end (does it make sense to store so much unrequired data at application level?) and then display as required based on IF conditions?

Comment: Depends. How much data? What is the use case? What sort of connection speed? Mobile or desktop? So many things to consider that we cant without background information. Its up to you where your users prefer to wait - at the start of the UI as it loads everything, or after they pick a selection and it has to read the second selection. Usually you wouldn't bring back a lot of data as it will impact performance too much on slower connections. But all depends on the use-case.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.